# C++ library for signal processing

Tags: c++, matlab, math, signal-processing

I wrote a research project in matlab that uses quite a few functions which I do not want to re-implement in C++, so I'm looking for libraries to handle these for me. The functions I need are: (by order of importance)

1. Hilbert transform
2. Matrix functions(determinant, inverse, multiplication...)
3. Finding roots of polynomials(for degrees greater than 5)
4. FFT
5. Convolutions
6. correlation(xcorr in matlab)

Comment: Have you tried looking for any of these yourself yet? What did you find?

Comment: These are all standard numeric routines, Google should overwhelm you with implementations, open-source, commercial and everything in-between.  As @Li-aung Yip asks -- what did you find ?

Comment: `Numerical Recipes in C` probably contains most of what you want...

Comment: Well I found `FFTW` to do FFT and inverse-FFT, I found an easy way to use that for Hilbert transforms, `Armadillo` for linear algebra, and the `GNU Scientific Library` that does pretty much everything under the sun. I would still love to hear what others use.

Comment: Consider asking on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've got an FFT you can knock off everything save for numbers 2. and 3.

The linear algebra requirement can be met with PETSc [www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/) which supports fftw.

I don't know how you're going to go about the root finding. You'll probably have to code that yourself (bisection, Newton's method etc etc.) but it's the easiest thing on the list to implement by far.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about most of those, but [`FFTW`](http://www.fftw.org/) is the 'fastest Fourier transform in the West'. It is used in the MATLAB implementation of `fft()`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the libraries that are available for use, but if you already have the functions written in matlab there is another option.

If you compile the matlab [functions to a dll](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-18CBI/index.html?solution=1-18CBI) they can be called by a c++ program. This would allow you to access the matlab functions that you already have without rewriting.